# ng-if not catching updated $scope values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been away from `angular 1.x` for so long I seem to have forgotten something important about `ng-if`. I have a function which updates a scope value whenever a carousel changes images which is tracking the active index of the carousel array.  I have `ng-if` set to remove one element and insert another when the index reaches the end of the array, something like this:

```
  <span ng-if="activeIndex < 4"
        class="back-button"
        ui-sref="app.profile.index({uID: user.uID})">
    Skip <i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>
  </span>

  <span ng-if="activeIndex === 4"
        class="skip-button"
        ui-sref="app.profile.index({uID: user.uID})">
    Continue <i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>
  </span>
```

but it isn't working. I believe that `ng-if` creates a new scope so that may be why it isn't catching the updated values, but if that is the case, what is an easy way to update the scope of `ng-if`? Or am I completely turned around?

Here's a `codepen` showing my problem: http://codepen.io/datatype_void/pen/zqjGOr?editors=1001

Comment: Why are you storing `$scope.activeIndex = '0';` as a string instead of `int`?

Comment: You are right, it creates a new scope. You could try ngHide and ngShow instead.

Comment: Btw, your maximum index in the pen you provided is `2`... You're comparing that with `4` in your `ng-if`...

Comment: Honest mistakes while retyping the code broseph, thanks for pointing out my errors though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `$scope.$apply();` after the activeIndex change, and that solved the problem.

```
function(swiper){
  $scope.activeIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
  $scope.$apply();
```

though I'm not sure why it isn't applied automatically.

Working code: http://codepen.io/C14L/pen/bpKrLo?editors=1111

(also changed the max value to 2 because it never got to 4 before, but that wasn't the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.updateIndex = function(index) {
    $timeout(function() {
         $scope.activeIndex = index;
    });
  };

  $scope.options = {
    autoplay: 300,
    speed: 500,
    effect: 'cube',
    onSlideChangeStart : function(swiper){
      if (swiper.activeIndex !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.updateIndex(swiper.activeIndex);
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.updateIndex(0);
});
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-if="activeIndex < 2"
      ui-sref="app.profile.index({uID: user.uID})">

  Skip <i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>
</span>

<span ng-if="activeIndex == 2"
      ui-sref="app.profile.index({uID: user.uID})">

  Continue <i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>
</span>
```

AngularJS provides $timeout, which is like setTimeout, but automatically wraps your code in $apply by default.

For more info:
http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/